# Azure Function - Managed certificate

Tags: azure, azure-function-app

I wanted to ask if I can create App Services managed certificates using powershell command? I tried to find such information, but unfortunately I did not manage to do so, and it would make my job much easier.

Second question - Can I find the certificate without using the thumbprint? After creating the certificate, I would like to assign it to a custom domain with a given name, but I was unable to "search" for the certificate by domain name, just using the exact thumbprint.

Thanks for any info!

Answer (score 0):

There are no direct power shell command let available by you can make a use of ARM template documented [here](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2021/03/02/asmc-apex-domain.html#automate-with-scripts).

coming to second store, thumbprint is the only way to extract certificate either from a given file system or from certificate store.
If you want certificate with domain then you need programming certificate to iterate over each certificate and fetch domain property of X509Certificate class.